# Conditions for convergence of $\frac{1}{1-\phi x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, geometric-series

It is defined in a note that

$\frac{1}{1-\phi x} = 1 + \phi x + (\phi x )^2 + … $

provided that $|\phi| < 1$ and $|x| \leq 1$.

Why it is necessarity to have $|x| \leq 1$ instead of $|x| < 1$.

Because if I let $z = \phi x$, this becomes a geometric series with $|z| < 1$. So $|ax| < 1$ implying that

(I) $|a| < 1$ and $|x| < 1$

(II) $|a| \leq 1$ and $|x| < 1$

(III) $|a| < 1$ and $|x| \leq 1$

Why do we pick only the last condition?

Edited:

I found this also in a time series book (Time series analysis and its applications)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many more possibilties ! For example $a=1/3$ and $x=2$, ....

Your question was: "Why do we pick only the last condition?"

My answer: " Ask the author of the note."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found something similar in a time series book. Please refer the edited post. Am I missing some important concept here?